# Иногда не могу найти элемент в словаре (dictionary) - Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, словари

Есть скрипт он проверяет есть ли объект на позиции - Если нет то Создает его Если есть то Игнорирует. Но проблема в том что он не может найти значение которое есть в словаре.

Словарь:

```
public Dictionary<Vector3, Chunk> chunkList = new Dictionary<Vector3, Chunk>();
```

Проверка:

```
if (!chunkList.ContainsKey(instPos))
{
    Debug.Log(instPos);
    InstantiateChunk(instPos);
}
```

Дебаг:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно не может найти вектор -32 0 -32 - хотя видим что в словаре есть такой элемент под номером 14

Comment: Здесь советую использовать кастомный IEqualityComparer: https://answers.unity.com/questions/551128/dictionary-with-vector3-as-key-cannot-be-child-gam.html

Comment: Да помогло, в моем случае порог до 0.11 поднял.

Comment: Ну тогда опишите своё решение ответом, думаю пригодится и другим посетителям.